# Loss of precision in NetCDF data when importing into python due to scale factor and offset

Tags: python, python-3.x, precision, netcdf, python-xarray

I have a NetCDF file that has been generated from a numerical simulation.
The data is stored using a scale factor and offset, an example from ncdump is as follows:

```
    float lon(lon) ;
        lon:long_name = "longitude" ;
        lon:standard_name = "coordinates_i" ;
        lon:units = "degrees_east " ;
        lon:scale_factor = 9.308405e-06f ;
        lon:add_offset = 118.9597f ;
```

This data should be smoothly varying from one value to another.

If I import this using either netcdf4 or xarray e'g' `data = xr.open_dataset('path/to/file')` then when I look at the coordinates data has been lost and they no longer vary smoothly. instead looking like
[image]

If I import using `data = xr.open_dataset('path/to/file', mask_and_scale=False)` then the data is smooth [image]

but this is not very useful as it does not contain the information I need (unscaled).
It looks to me like there is a precision issue whereby the 'smoothness' in the data is at too high a decimal place and has been lost.

So my question is, is there a way to increase precision when importing so that the data remains smooth, and doesn't become stepwise, whilst using scalefactor and offset? perhaps using the `decimal` module or something?

Alternatively, is there a way to import the stored data, scale factor, and offset separately. and then apply them in my python script where I can enforce better precision?

I have tried a few different approaches so far and nothing seems to work.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Possibly related issue: https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/2304

Comment: The `scale_factor` and `add_offset` can be retrieved from the DataArray `encoding` property. In your case I would try `data.lon.encoding` to retrieve these values by using `mask_and_scale=False`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a malformed variable. `scale_factor` and `add_offset` should only annotate data that are packed (e.g., to `short`), yet this variable has the same numeric type as those packing attributes.

Extended answer in response to questions below:
IMHO coordinates (lat, lon) should rarely be packed. That said, to pack the coordinate in this example correctly, one would scale and offset the coordinates with the indicated factors, and then demote and save the array in any datatype that requires less storage (e.g., 2-byte shorts) than the native 4-byte float data, then `ncdump` would show `short lon(lon)` and all else would be the same. xarray appears to be confused by the malformed data and quantizes it on input.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. I didn't write the code that generates output, so thanks for pointing out what is wrong. From my reading am I correct in saying that after off-setting and scaling the data should be written as int to file?

Out of interest why does this result in the issues I see - is it the precision issue I suggest in the question?